# How to filter date with golang and mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to query records from mongodb using golang but seems like it's not working. I tried running the query with mongo cli using ISODate() and it works but I'm not sure how to call ISODate with golang. Below is a snippet of the code I'm running.

```
type Record struct{
    ID         primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    PropertyID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"propertyID"`
    CreatedAt  primitive.DateTime `bson:"createdAt"`
}
// ....
cur, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{"createdAt": bson.M{
    "$gte": time.Now().UTC().AddDate(-1, 0, 0).Format(time.RFC3339),
}})
// ....
var recs []Record
err = cur.All(ctx, &recs)
```

if I run `len(recs)` I get 0 but in mongo-cli I'm getting result when I run code below.

```
db.getCollection('records').find({
    createdAt: {
        $gte: ISODate("2019-11-02T23:16:58+08:00")
    }
}).sort({createdAt: -1})
```

by the way **2019-11-02T23:16:58+08:00** is the output of `time.Now().UTC().AddDate(-1, 0, 0).Format(time.RFC3339)`

Thanks in advance guys :D

Comment: Declare `CreatedDate` as `time.Time`, and use a `time.Time` in the query

Comment: Thanks, all answers were valid and are working. The funny part is I've used also used `primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime` but I thought it was not working because there's no record but when I logged the error returned by `cur.All(ctx, &rec)` now I see the problem. Some records have undefined as a propertyID.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try [primitive.NewObjectIDFromTimestamp](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#NewObjectIDFromTimestamp).

From there you can convert `time.Time` to `primitive.ObjectID` and vice versa.

```
func NewObjectIDFromTimestamp(timestamp time.Time) ObjectID
```

> NewObjectIDFromTimestamp generates a new ObjectID based on the given time.

Or [primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#NewDateTimeFromTime), what creates a `DateTime`.

```
func NewDateTimeFromTime(t time.Time) DateTime
```

> NewDateTimeFromTime creates a new DateTime from a Time.

And then pass that to your query filter like this:

```
cur, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{"createdAt": bson.M{
    "$gte": primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(time.Now().AddDate(-1, 0, 0)),
}})
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `CreatedAt` is of type `primitive.Datetime`, in your `bson.M` query on `CreatedAt` you need to pass `primitive.Datetime` object.

Golang's mongo driver handles marshaling for you.

```
cur, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{"createdAt": bson.M{
    "$gte": primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(time.Now())
}})
```

Comment: Is `primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(…)` really necessary? Everybody says so, but for me, it also works with a naked `time.Now()`.

Comment: `filter := bson.M{"ts": bson.M{"$gte": time.Now().UTC().Format(time.RFC3339),},}` this is also alternative

Answer (score 2):

Here a simple sample using bson.D and aggregation:

```
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"

    mongo.Pipeline{
            {{"$match", bson.D{
                {"createdAt", bson.D{
    {"$gt", primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -30))}}}},
            }}}
    }
```